# Angular2 auth guard fails to work

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

What am trying to do is to protect the auth routes to ensure that only non authenticated users can access and the autheticated users are automatically redirrected to the dashboard.

Checking if a person is authenticated am doing:

1. Checking if an access token exists in localstorage and if it doesnt... he is authenticated
2. If a token exists check with the php(server) if its a valid one

I have tried the following

In the routes

```
 {path: 'auth', loadChildren: 'app/auth/auth.module#AuthModule', canActivate: [UnAuthenticatedGuardService]},
```

Now the `UnAuthenticatedGuardService`

```
@Injectable()
 export class UnAuthenticatedGuardService implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>|boolean {

    return new Observable(observer=>{
       this._authService.checkLoggedin().subscribe(
        (res) => {
         if(res){
             this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
            return false
          } 
            return observer.next(!res)
         },
       (err) => {
         return observer.next(false)
    })
  });

}
```

Now in my `authservice`

```
@Injectable()
 export class AuthService {


checkLoggedin(): Observable<boolean> {    
 if(!this._accesstokenService.getToken('access_token')){
     return Observable.of(false); //just checks for localstorage
   }

 //if the access token exists takes it and checks if its a valid one on the server
 return this._httpclient.get(this.authurl + '/default/is-loggedin')
   .map((res) => {
      return res;
    }, (error) => {
      return Observable.of(false);
    }
  );
```

}

Where am i going wrong as the above fails execution when a token exists and doesnt process the server response to check if an access token exists.
THat is if an access token already exists a request is made to the server to check if its valid but its response is never passed to the unauthenticatedguard

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've vastly overcomplicated it, just do this in your guard:

```
return this._authService.checkLoggedin().catch(loggedIn => { 
   this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
   return Observable.of(false);
});
```

and make your auth check do this instead to consistently handle invalid auth with an error response:

```
checkLoggedin(): Observable<boolean> {    
 if(!this._accesstokenService.getToken('access_token')){
    return Observable.throw(false); //just checks for localstorage
 }

 //if the access token exists takes it and checks if its a valid one on the server
 return this._httpclient.get(this.authurl + '/default/is-loggedin')
   .map((res) => {
      return res;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplification but now am getting an error on return Observable.of(false); that Observable_1.Observable.of is not a function

Comment: thanks i see ihave added import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch' and now it works

Answer (score 1):

Oh buddy. I could be wrong, but it looks like you are making it a little bit more complicated than it needs to be. I do not make heavy use of `observables` but just wondering: Why aren't you wrapping `res` with `Observable.of` like you do with all the other items? Also, what is the `response.code` for your call to `/default/is-loggedin`, because I am pretty sure any `2xx` or `3xx` code will not throw the error you have in the request.

Here is how I implemented similar functionality of guarding against an authenticated user from going to the homepage and instead redirecting to the dashboard:

`main-auth-guard`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { UserService } from '../services/user.service'

@Injectable()
export class MainAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private user: UserService, 
    private router: Router
  ){}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

      /**
       * If the currentUser exists, the user should be able to go to this page. If not, it should not be able to.
       */

      if ( state.url === "/") {
        if ( this.user.currentUser() ) {
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
          return false;
        } else if ( this.user.getLSToken()) {
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
          return false;
        }
      }

      return true;
  }
}
```

And my `user.service` ( I removed non pertinent parts of it )

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  user:IClientUser;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient, 
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  /**
 * Get's the Local Storage token.
 */
  getLSToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem("token");
  }

  currentUser() {
    return this.user;
  }

 //...
```